# Why can't a PC connect to a specific website while all the others work?

Tags: windows-7, home-networking, internet-connection

A PC is connected via a router and a modem to a local network. All the webpages seem to work fine, yet the [webpage of a local libary](https://webopac.stadtbibliothek-leipzig.de/webOPACClient/start.do?BaseURL=this), will not load independent of the used browser. Other devices on the same and other networks will load it without any problem.

All the PC will get is a blank white page no matter the browser (Chrome, Opera, and Firefox were tried).

Chrome shows the error message: ERR_CONNECTION_RESET after a while, and recommending to check the state of the Internet connection. Yet the PC is connected to the Internet just fine, it just refuses to load this one specific page.

What reason could there be?

I already tried resetting the DNS cache via:

```
ipconfig /flushdns
```

to no avail. What other causes of this behavior could there be?

Comment: Seems related, working myself through the answers there: http://superuser.com/questions/169024/cant-access-any-microsoft-website-others-are-fine

Comment: what does your HOST file say? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file) Did you check your AV?

Comment: try "ping example.com" and see if the IP you get is the same on other machines